# How to fix event handler not opening in code window after renaming my form?

Tags: vb.net

I am running into an issue after I rename my existing form in Visual Studio 2022. After I rename my form and try to double click a button control in the design window to open it up in the code editor, it doesn't create the event handler.

I tried double clicking the control before renaming the form and it worked just fine. But after I renamed the form, it didn't. I renamed the form in the solutions explorer window, so I am not sure if that is the reason why it's happening?

I haven't had an issue like this before, so if anyone has an idea on why this is happening and how to fix it, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Click the 'Show All Files' button in the Solution Explorer and expand that form. Do you see all the expected nodes under it? Can you open the designer, the designer code file and the user code file?

Answer (score 0):

You should try checking Form name property if it is correct try Re-build or restart solution.

Answer (score 0):

If u rename then design form , make sure same name reflect in code page also also, if not then rename their also.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was going on! I was using WinForms App instead of the Windows Form App (.NET Framework). Switching to the other application let me rename my form with ease.